# How to calculate a bungee jump without using conservation of energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, integration

A bungee jumper jumps off a cliff with a cord of unstretched length $L$ and a spring constant $k$. His mass is $m$ and assume that the cliff is big enough so that he doesn't hit the ground. What is the maximum speed he reaches?

This problem is pretty easy when using conservation of energy, by just letting speed be his change in total energy of jumping. However, I tried doing this problem a different way and couldn't get the same answer.

My approach is to integrate over the accelerations of the bungee jumper as he is falling down and the cord is pulling him up and then add that to the velocity he already has before the cord is stretched out. I couldn't make the integral work out how do I do it?

Comment: Please show your attempt and ask about a conceptual difficulty. Probably failure to *make the integral work out* is not a conceptual difficulty. If your only difficulty is how to solve an integral, that is a math question rather than a physics question.

Comment: No, I dont know how to set it up? Maybe $\int_{0}^{x} g - 1/2kx^2$

Comment: But that doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure whatever integral is correct is trivial to solve.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x} g - 1/2kx^2$ is an incorrect attempt to use conservation of energy.

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Using conservation of energy is not trivial here, as not all of the potential energy is converted into kinetic energy. The velocity is at its maximum, when the gravitational force is exactly counteracted by the spring force. But at this point, the spring is already extended and contains some of the initial potential energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use conservation of energy, you could use the equations of motion.

$$
F = ma = m\ddot x
$$

where the force $F$ has a gravity contribution $mg$ and a harmonic spring contribution $-kx$. Together with your initial conditions $x(0) = 0$, $v(0) = v_0$, you can solve this harmonic oscillator with gravity. This will give you $v(t)$ from which you can determine the maximum velocity.

No energies considered here.